# Adverb versus instrumental case in time expressions

Tags: грамматика, падежи

In time expressions, I'm confused whether I'm looking at an adverb or a noun in instrumental case.

For example, **летом** can be an adverb meaning *in summer*, or the instrumental case of **лето** (*summer*).

And **вечером** can be an adverb meaning *in the evening*, or the instrumental case of **вечер** (*evening*).

Now take these two sentences:

1) Может быть, они приедут к нам **летом**.

2) Мы ждём гостей в субботу **вечером**.

What is the form of летом and вечером?

Comment: I like your question. For me, it is no difference at all and no one cares. In your sample, I suppose both instances are adverbs. But really, why not a noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are adverbs.

Try replacing the words with a question:

> Может быть, они приедут к нам *чем*?
>
> Мы ждём гостей в субботу *чем*?

This makes no sense.

However, in a more complex example:

> Может быть, они приедут к нам *жарким летом*

, *жарким летом* is an adverbial phrase (answering the question *когда?*) which consists of a noun and an adjective.

Comment: *Phrase* is better, there's no *clause*

Comment: @V.V.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause

Comment: I  wonder if you read it.

Comment: @V.V. my bad, sorry!

Comment: @Quassnoi is there any explanation for why *жаркий* is used in instrumental case in this adverbial phrase? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As stated Quassnoi, those are adverbs, and question "чем?" makes no sense. No sense - today. This is by definition of adverbs. But how was adverbs appeared long time ago? There were some meaning words , which was stripped. This is implication. I attempt to reconstruct such words: For example. 
Может быть, они приедут к нам тогда, когда пора года явится (чем?) летом.
Or: ... тогда, когда жизнь природы обернётся\воспринимается (чем?) летом.
Or: ... тогда, когда пора воспринимается (чем?) летом\вечером.
Thought, it is semanticly correct, but no one say it.

Sorry for my english.